# Low Requests per second with Catalyst perl MVC framework

Tags: performance, perl, catalyst

I'm new to web apps development and I don't know what RPS(requests per second) considered to be normal for dynamic site, however I think that my app very slow.

I'm now working on 4th part of Catalyst::Manual::Tutorial and now I have ~45 RPS for reading 5-10 entries from DB and only about 3-5 RPS for updating/creating/deleting data in DB. I'm using all tools mentioned in tutorial, i.e. SQLite3, Catalyst 5.90075 with perl 5.18 on linux. In DB I have 2 tables with data(author and book) and 1 link table(author_book), my HDD speed ~120MiB/s for read/write and core i5 intel processor.

I have 2 controllers, 1 model and 4 chained actions in my app and using development server(tried Starman with absolutely same results, don't tried perl_mod with Apache for now). Suppose I'm doing something wrong... Can somebody help to improve perfomance?

Comment: Have you check the memory? Does it swap?

Comment: No, I haven't swapping at all. I have 4 GiB of RAM. Development servers takes ~100MiB and Starman depending on number of workers

Comment: I recommand you run it against a profiler and see where the time spent. See http://www.slideshare.net/Tim.Bunce/nyt-prof-201406key

Comment: Those times sound typical when a DB is involved. I get up to 250+ when it’s flat or cached data. You can, and should, run multiple processes (limited by RAM) thus multiplying the effective RPS. uWSGI is better than Starman in pretty much every way and works fine with .psgi and Catalyst.

Comment: Ok, I found that Catalyst(by default) using DBIx in such a way that it creates 1 SELECT per entry, rather that 1 SELECT for all entries. But why it's chosen as default behaviour? Each SELECT costs ~2.2ms(info from NYTProf, most expensive is sub DBIx::Class::Storage::DBIHacks::_resolve_aliastypes_from_select_args) and it's incredibly expensive to do such things as Catalyst does... In the case of INSERTs the most expensive is DBI::st:execute(xsub) and suppose there is no way to improve this(in case of INSERT)...

P.S. Thanks a lot for NYTProf, very nice tool

Answer (score 1):

You should add [Catalyst::Stats](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst%3A%3AStats) to you project and get the duration of different parts of you code. This will enable to figure out what is the bottleneck.